# SQLAlchemy order by field of first element of relationship list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In an application with Flask and SQLAlchemy, there are two models,

Person (id, name, email, ..., roles=relatioship('PersonRole') )

and

PersonRole (id, role_id, level_of_access, zone, ..., person=relationship('person', ...) ),

where role_id is a value from a predefined dictionary. A person can have multiple roles and these roles are in a certain order in the roles list. In the UI, only the first role of the roles list is displayed. How can I sort the persons by a field (let's say level_of_acces) of the first element of the roles list of a Person?

Comment: Can't you sort it in memory (in Python)?

Comment: No, it won't work, I think it should be solved with hybrid methods/properties.